# Cannot cd into /Windows/System32/config/ from Kali Linx

Tags: kali-linux, windows, password

I have tried to reset my Windows 7 password using Kali Linux which is dual booted with Windows 7.

I read a few pages and have followed the following steps:

```
cd /media/448AF1848AF172B2
cd /Windows/System32/config/
chntpw SAM
```

After I try the `cd /Windows/System32/config/` part I get the error:

```
bash: cd: /Windows/System32/config: No such file or directory
```

Here is a list of partitions:

```
Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks      Id  System
/dev/sda1            2046    31459327    15728641    5  Extended
/dev/sda2   *    31459328    31664127      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3        31664128   260026367   114181120    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       260026368   488394751   114184192    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda5            2048    31459327    15728640   83  Linux
```

Source:
[How-To Geek - Change Your Forgotten Windows Password with the Linux System Rescue CD](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/change-your-forgotten-windows-password-with-the-linux-system-rescue-cd/)

Answer (score 2):

If the directory you want to go to is `/media/448AF1848AF172B2/Windows/System32/config/`, you can go there in two steps with:

```
cd /media/448AF1848AF172B2
cd Windows/System32/config
```

Note: the argument to the second `cd` command must not begin with `/` if you want to continue from the directory specified with the first `cd` command.

A pathname starting with a slash `/` is an *absolute path*: it is always interpreted starting at the root of the filesystem hierarchy. Your second `cd /Windows/...` command had a slash at the beginning, so it did not continue from where the first `cd` command left off, but tried to trace a completely different path starting from the root directory of the system - a path that did not exist.

In your solution, you have two `cd` commands with absolute paths:

```
cd /media/448AF1848AF172B2
cd /media/448AF1848AF172B2/Windows/System32/config
```

As your goal is to get to `/media/448AF1848AF172B2/Windows/System32/config`, the first command is completely unnecessary: the second command will get you to the exact directory you specified, no matter what your current directory was before it.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution after playing around for a while. I will show the steps I took for anyone with a similar problem:

```
cd /media/448AF1848AF172B2/Windows/System32/config
chntpw -l sam
chntpw -u Rahul_2 sam
```

You should see this

```
- - - - User Edit Menu:
 1 - Clear (blank) user password
 2 - Edit (set new) user password (careful with this on XP or Vista)
 3 - Promote user (make user an administrator)
 4 - Unlock and enable user account [probably locked now]
 q - Quit editing user, back to user select
```

Select `2` to change the password.